# How to deal with series of the form $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}f(n)^{(-1)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have no idea on how to prove series like $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left(\frac{1}{n^x}\right)^{(-1)^n}$$ for natural $x$ -divergent or convergent. By intuition it seems they diverge .

Comment: Look at pairs of terms. I.e., only even or only odd partial sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking $k=n/2$ the sum can be written as (without $n=1$, which is not relevant to convergence):
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k)^x}+{(2k+1)}^x$$
Which is clearly diverges.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

A necessary condition for the convergence of the series $\displaystyle \sum_n a_n$ is that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$.

Comment: so you are saying this series is not convergent... :O

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: yes yes.. I agree! :)

Comment: You "do" hints really well! +1